# ImportError: cannot import name 'label_map_util'

Tags: python-3.6

I'm running on Python 3.6.5 (64bits) trying to run the object_detection_tutorial.

I receive this message when I run the programm :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'label_map_util'
```

Any idea on what I should do ?

Edit : I tried to see whether or not I installed the API and got this :

```
C:\tensorflow\models-master>python object_detection/protos/label_map_util_test.py
python: can't open file 'object_detection/protos/label_map_util_test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
```

Comment: i tried already and got this : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leahj\Desktop\object_detection_tutorial.py", line 43, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Comment: okay, sorry.  There is more information with what appears to be a similar problem here... https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1990

Comment: Yup, that's were I went first to find an answer.. but it didn't work out

Comment: I found some solutions using protobuff 3.3 I'm currently using the 3.4 version. Am I still going to get results if I use the 3.3 ? (edit:looking at it right now!)

Comment: Ok I'm just starting so I think I lack some crucial notions. They are talking about path in many answers, could you please tell me exactly for what it stands for, please ?

Comment: The path is the ability for windows to know where certain programs and files are located.  So if I wanted to go to a windows command line and type Python, if I expect windows to know about Python and how to use Python to execute programs, Python has to be added to the path.   A video like this shows what I mean... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWVoCVaqRww

Comment: CD to object_detection directory and then run the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Get current dir :

`os.getcwd()`
change current dir :
`os.chdir( '../models/research/object_detection' )`

CD to object_detection directory

And you can replace

from utils import label_map_util to

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
```

and

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util to

`from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util`